# What are the limits for ADO data types?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I'm trying to determine the appropriate ADO Command Parameter data types to use for calling a SQL Server (2005) stored procedure. I was specifically first trying to determine the appropriate ADO data type that would correspond to a SQL Server data type of `varchar(MAX)`. I think it might be `adVarChar`, but I'm not sure.

Why isn't the size (e.g. number of characters for 'string' types, range for numeric types) for each of these data types *listed in the documentation*?! And why is it seemingly impossible to find a handy table listing each of the data types and the *maximum amount of info you can stuff in each of them*?! You'd think someone would notice the probably *millions* of questions related to variants of "Why is my data being truncated?" ...

**Clarification** – The above info is merely a concrete example illustrating the utility of knowing the limits of the ADO data types, e.g. to choose an appropriate ADO data type to handle specific data types for various data sources.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp

Comment: @Fink – why not include that link in an answer? I found that table when I was searching, but it doesn't actually answer my question. And based on the info in the answer made by GSerg, it's not entirely correct – according to the table at that link the ADO data type `adVarChar` corresponds to the SQL Server data type `varchar`, but supposedly that's not true for `varchar(MAX)` (and that data type isn't listed separately).

Comment: @Kenny I added an abstract to address that part of your question.

Comment: you mentioned not being able to find a table of the ado data types.  I didn't know the answer but thought it might be of some assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Specific part

`varchar(MAX)` can be used from ADO as an input parameter.
The data type in this case would be `adLongVarChar`, max length is `&h7FFFFFFF`, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

It cannot be used as an output parameter though.
Nor can it be consumed as a field type in a returned recordsed (funny -- `.Value` is `Empty`, because it's actually a long type, but `GetChunk` may not be called to retrieve the actual data because ADO thinks it's not a long type).

If you need to consume `varchar(MAX)` as an output parameter using VBA/ADO, you will have to `select` it to return a recordset to the client, and you will have to cast it to `text` while doing that:

```
select cast(@var as text) as data;
return 0;
```

Then you would say `s = .Fields(0).GetChunk(.Fields(0).ActualSize)` to get the data from the opened recordset.

---

### Abstract part

The very point of ADO is to abstract away differences between different data sources. As soon as there's a data access driver around that supports an interface, you (ideally) may talk to it without bothering what it is.

As any abstraction, this one is also [leaky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

The exact knowledge of what data types of what servers map to which ADO data types comes from experience. That is.

Some rules of thumb, hovewer, may be developed quite quickly:

- It is not difficult to figure possible ADO data types by matching their names with data type names of the particular server:

  - `int - adInteger`
  - `datetime - adDBDate` (although here you might be forced into some trial and error)
- Certain data types are called BLOBs (binary large objects). They are designed to contain a huge piece of data and usually presented in the data source documentation as such. For these, a corresponding ADO data type is likely to contain `Long` in its name, which, in ADO world, means "BLOB" (`adLongVarBinary`, `adLongVarChar`, `adLongVarWChar`).
- Any information on exact length of a data type is to be found in the documentation for the data source, not the ADO documentation. For things like:

  - Maximum length set by a developer for a specific column in this particular table (such as `varchar(10)`)
  - Maximum theoretical length of a BLOB data type (such as `varchar(max)`)

  you are going to consult the corresponding data source, not ADO.

Comment: Great addition to your answer! [And I just learned that `varchar(MAX)` was deliberately intended to replace `text` (and can hold the same number of characters). That makes your implied claim that `varchar(MAX)` is a BLOB data type make more sense to me.]

Comment: I realize this is a rather old thread but . . . text is deprecated in SQL Server.  Would we follow the same idea but use varchar(max) instead of text?  I have an output parameter declared as varchar(max) that is getting truncated to 8000 chars in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `Text` had already been deprecated when I wrote this. Still, it's not removed yet, and it's the only thing ADO not .net will understand. How can you use varchar(max) instead of text in the first place? What I'm showing is a workaround in order to get varchar(max) data via ADO. It is not truncated on the server side, check the tools you are using to retrieve the data.

Comment: @AGSerg . . . thank you for the response and for the useful answer.  We found a work-around, because we can retrieve varchar(max) from a table.  So, the result will go into a table and be fetched using a select.

Comment: Also SQL Server does not support the adDBDate datatype.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214459/en