# SQL SP not returning a value to ADO execute

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

OK, I'm missing something obvious here - I have an SP that takes in an integer ID and returns a string.  I've used this SP for quite a while with DAO.  Now I need to switch to ADO so I can run it under and existing connection (another question I'll post elsewhere).

So my code follows.  It returns no errors but it also returns no results.  The output parameter is null.  What am I missing?

---

```
Dim adoCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoCMD As ADODB.Command
Dim SQLstr As String
Dim ConStr As String

'--- get connection string from existing object, but strip leading odbc; piece
ConStr = Replace(CurrentDb.TableDefs("[TableName]").Connect, "ODBC;", "")

Set adoCon = New ADODB.Connection
adoCon.ConnectionString = ConStr
adoCon.Open

Set adoCMD = New ADODB.Command
With adoCMD
    .ActiveConnection = adoCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamReturnValue, , Null)  ' return value
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("Path", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 500, Null)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("AsyID", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Item("AsyID").Value = AsyID
    .CommandText = "dbo.spGetAncestry"
    .Execute
End With

GetHeritage = adoCMD.Parameters(1).Value   'parm(0) = 0; parm(1) = NULL; parm(2) = AsyID

adoCon.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code should work. Please remove the optional expressions in the parameter definition and try the following:

```
Dim rv as Integer
Set adoCMD = New ADODB.Command
With adoCMD
    .ActiveConnection = adoCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("Path", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 500)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("AsyID", adInteger, adParamInput, , AsyID)
    .CommandText = "dbo.spGetAncestry"
    .Execute
End With

rv = adoCMD.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE").Value

GetHeritage = adoCMD.Parameters("Path").Value
```

also make sure your SP is returning the correct data type and size for your output parameter and adjust the code accordingly. If you're returning VARCHAR(MAX), then that is treated as a "BLOB" in ADO, see this related question [What are the limits for ADO data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905003/what-are-the-limits-for-ado-data-types).
In this case you can try returning varchar(8000) from the SP and updating the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, jbud.  I tried your suggestions - no change in the result.  The SP has the same type and size as what is declared here - VARCHAR(500).  The actual results run around 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
Apparently, in the ADO call, it doesn't matter what you set the return value to (I was trying to use "" or even " " before I set it to null) when it executes in SQL batch, it is simply set to NULL as it shows in this trace form.  For this run, the Output was initialized as " ", but the batch passed in NULL.
[!SQL trace of the above query being executed with " " in the initialization of the Output variable[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcWNr.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcWNr.png)

Normally, a null wouldn't be a problem as the typical SP assignment would be:
**SET @Path = [SELECT value from table]**
or, if it was a concatenation, you would initialize the variable:
**SET @Path = ''**
before stringing together the input.
In this particular case, though, the SP is recursive.  It calls itself passing an input and the output values to the new copy.  Because of this, you can't initialize the value and you can't use a straight assignment.  To get around this, I needed to use:
**@path = COALESCE(@path, '') + [SELECT value from table]**
to trap any NULL passed in.

Comment: For future readers, can you legibly re-write this answer which can be helpful? Specifically, please *show* (don't tell) what in the SP or VBA code should change. And if nothing should change, explicitly say so. Thanks.